# Excel vba - Save macro enabled file as macro disabled file with chart

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro enabled file that creates a chart from some calculations.
I want to use a vba to save this file on a click and archive it for future use. My current code throws me a

> Run-time error '1004': The specified dimension is not valid for the current chart type.

Is there a fix for my code, or I'll have to find different way of doing this?

```
Public Sub Archive()
    Dim savePath As String
    savePath = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A220").Text

    Dim saveDir

    saveDir = "\\Fileserver\common\departments\Unit C\Administrative\KPI\Overtimes\" & Format(Date, "yyyy") & "-Overtime hours\" & Format(Date, "mm") & ". " & Format(Date, "mmmm") & "\"
        If Dir(saveDir, vbDirectory) = "" Then
            Shell ("cmd /c mkdir """ & saveDir & """")
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
        End If

    Worksheets(Array("Tracker", "Data")).Copy
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=savePath, FileFormat:=xlWorkbookDefault '**<<<This one fails even if I remove the chart from the spreadsheet**
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

> EDIT Below (Error screenshot attached)

[image]

> SOLUTION
>
> I had ".xlxm" at the end of the savePath string. When I removed it
>   worked for me.
>
> Not sure why, possibly because I am already specifying the file format
>   as a parameter to the SaveAs function.
>
> Thank for all who tried to help.

Comment: I don't see it - your error message is about the chart, but the code is about the saving procedure.

Comment: Save with fileformat = xlOpenXMLWorkbook

Comment: Tried also with xlOpenXMLWorkbook, same error popped up

Comment: Sorry all, the solution was to remove the ".xlsm" from the filename string. It worked when I removed it. Will edit the question to add it on the bottom. Thanks for looking into it anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this as an answer only to appear on search as solved. Also it might help someone else with similar issues.

I only removed the extension from the filename (".xlxm") from the filename string.